# How to call a sas dataset by its label or where to check its name

Tags: server, sas, label, enterprise-guide

I have a problem in dealing with SAS Enterprise Guide that runs on the server of my client.
I do not have access to the libraries so, in order to use the datasets the only thing we can do is to store them on the local disk C: of the computer and drag them to SAS. 
We can not create libraries because the server does not read local paths.

Once you drag a table, let's call it "mydata" in SAS, the table is automatically renamed "mydata9865" with random numbers at the end and "mydata" is its label.
If you right-click the table and go to properties, you can't find the name of the table, just the label.

The only way I found to check the real name of the dataset is to open the Query Builder and check the name in the code preview. 
The problem is that I am dealing with tables of millions of records and the machine I am using is very slow, so whenever I want to open the Query Building, just to check the table's name, it takes sometimes even an hour.

I am not a SAS expert, so I am sure there is a smarter way to do so. Is it possible for instance to use the table by calling it with its label?

```
data mydata2;
set mydata;
run;
```

instead of

```
set mydata9865?
```

Or is there some place I can rapidly check the name of the table without going through the query builder?

I tried to google it but I can't find anything, I hope someone will be able to help me!

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not understand your description. What are you "dragging"?  Do you mean to say that the SAS server you are using with EG is running on a different machine that EG itself?  Or perhaps you meant that you are somehow running EG itself on a windows Server instead of your laptop?  Can you place the datasets you want to access in a place where the SAS server can see them?  Such as a shared network disk.  The server might use a different path than how you see them from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hover the mouse pointer over a data node to see it's attributes.  The data set name is the **File name:** value.

For example:

[image]

In this example I had renamed the nodes created by two different queries to be the same (doable:yes, smart:maybe not).  NOTE: A data node **Label:** is not necessarily the same as it's underlying data set's label metadata.

Regarding

> use the table by calling it with its label?

Two nodes can have the same label, and is a a situation that defeats this approach.

Comment: Doesn't work either, I see the local path instead of the name in my situation

Comment: What is the actual file name attribute value (local path) shown for the node in your situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the COPY task to upload your data explicitly. It sounds like you're not adding your data to the projects properly so SAS automatically assigns a name, rather than if you explicitly import or load your data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I should have simply upload the data to the server with Tasks->Data->Upload Data Sets to Server but I didn't know this task so I didn't know it was possible to do it at all!

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Importing-sas-data-sets-from-C-drive-into-SAS-EG-not-possible/td-p/135184

Thank you everybody for you help!